# ConTeXt: xtables zebra stripe

Tags: color, context, backgrounds, extreme-tables

## Background

Set up zebra striping using extreme tables. The ConTeXt tables are generated by converting an ASCII Markdown table via pandoc.

## Minimum Example

```
\starttext
  \startplacetable[]
  \startxtable
  \startxtablehead[head]
  \startxrow
  \startxcell Item \stopxcell
  \startxcell[align=left] Cost (\$) \stopxcell
  \startxcell[align=left] Description \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody[body]
  \dorecurse{4}{
  \startxrow
  \startxcell Item \stopxcell
  \startxcell[align=left] 100 \stopxcell
  \startxcell[align=left] Cow text \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  }
  \stopxtablebody
  \startxtablefoot[foot]
  \startxrow
  \startxcell {\bf Total} \stopxcell
  \startxcell[align=left] {\bf 400} \stopxcell
  \startxcell[align=left]  \stopxcell
  \stopxrow
  \stopxtablefoot
  \stopxtable
  \stopplacetable
\stoptext
```

## Problem

ConTeXt, which is rather consistent with its `setup` macros, [does not appear](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/xtables-mkiv.pdf) to define a `\setupxrow` or `\setupxcell`. I had anticipated something like:

```
\definecolor[lime][r=0.75, g=1, b=0] 
\definecolor[transparentred][r=1,t=.5,a=1]
\setupxrow[odd][background=lime]
\setupxrow[even][background=transparentred]
```

This did not compile.

## Question

Without using `definextable` to create a custom xtable definition, how would you apply [zebra striping](https://alistapart.com/article/zebrastripingdoesithelp) so that every other non-header row has a coloured background?

## Update

It appears as though the `OverlayBox` is off by a few points.

[image: OverlayBox Edges]

The configuration code:

```
\definecolor[ColourTertiaryLt][h=a6b6b8]

\setupfloat[table][default={here,split}]

\setupxtable[
  frame=off,
  split=yes,
  header=repeat,
  framecolor=ColourTertiary,
]
\setupxtable[head][
  topframe=on,
  bottomframe=on,
]
\setupxtable[body][]
\setupxtable[foot][
  bottomframe=on,
]

\startuseMPgraphic {tablebackground}
  fill OverlayBox withcolor \MPcolor{ColourTertiaryLt} ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[tablebackground][
  \ifnum\currentxtablerow>1
    \ifodd\currentxtablerow\else
      \useMPgraphic{tablebackground}%
    \fi
  \fi
]

\setupxtable[background=tablebackground]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With **natural tables** this would have been easy because the environment let you set different values for **even** and **odd** rows.

```
\startsetups [tablebackground]
  \setupTABLE [row] [odd] [background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\bTABLE[setups=tablebackground]
\dorecurse{9}{\bTR \expanded{\bTD Row \recurselevel \eTD} \eTR}
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Extreme tables on the other hand don’t support this kind of setup and you have to use the `overlay` mechanism to create your own backgrounds for the cells.

In the overlay setting you can check the value of the `\currentxtablerow` counter to apply a different command for **odd** and **even** rows.

```
\startuseMPgraphic {tablebackground}
    fill OverlayBox withcolor \MPcolor{gray} ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [tablebackground]
  [\ifodd\currentxtablerow
     \useMPgraphic{tablebackground}%
   \fi]

\starttext

\startxtable[background=tablebackground]
\dorecurse{9}{\startxrow \expanded{\startxcell Row \recurselevel \stopxcell} \stopxrow}
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```

To skip the table header:

```
\defineoverlay
  [tablebackground]
  [\ifnum\currentxtablerow>1
     \ifodd\currentxtablerow\useMPgraphic{tablebackground}\fi
   \fi]
```

To apply shading against even rows:

```
\startuseMPgraphic {tablebackground}
  fill OverlayBox withcolor \MPcolor{gray} ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [tablebackground]
  [\ifnum\currentxtablerow>1
     \ifodd\currentxtablerow \else
       \useMPgraphic{tablebackground}%
     \fi
   \fi]

\setupxtable[background=tablebackground]
```

To apply the background against all tables in the document, use:

```
\setupxtable[background=tablebackground]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility, based on [Wolfgang's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464771/2148), is to define a macro that returns a colour suitable for use with the `backgroundcolor` option of `setupxtable`. For example:

```
\definecolor[ColourTertiaryLt][h=a6b6b8]

\def\TableBackgroundColour{%
  \ifnum\currentxtablerow>1
    \ifodd\currentxtablerow\else
      ColourTertiaryLt%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\setupxtable[
  frame=off,
  split=yes,
  header=repeat,
  option={stretch,width},
  framecolor=ColourTertiaryDk,
]
\setupxtable[head][
  topframe=on,
  bottomframe=on,
]
\setupxtable[body][
  background=color,
  backgroundcolor=\TableBackgroundColour,
]
\setupxtable[foot][
  bottomframe=on,
]
```

This avoids dropping into MetaPost and uses the underlying frame's background colour, which will fill itself nearly perfectly.

To include zebra striping of the footer, move the background setup options for `\setupxtable[body]` into the first `\setupxtable` (then `\setupxtable[body]` can be removed entirely):

```
\setupxtable[
  frame=off,
  split=yes,
  header=repeat,
  option={stretch,width},
  framecolor=ColourTertiaryDk,
  background=color,
  backgroundcolor=\TableBackgroundColour,
]
```